# Putting unrelated histories behind each other

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase, git-rewrite-history

For some reason (due to complicated conversion from SVN) I have two Git repositories:

- git repo A contains all history up to 31st December 2021
- git repo B contains all history from 1st January 2022 on

Now I would like to "merge" them in a way that I have the whole history, i.e. first the `main` branch of repo A and then the `main` branch from repo B.

I have not really understood yet how to do this properly.

- If I just merge the two repos, then I get a merge commit at the end, which is also pretty meaningless because I do not want to have the content of repo A merged into B, since B is more recent.
- If I rebase the main of B on the main of A I get kind of what I wanted but I am not sure whether the newly generated commits (from the ones of repo B) may have content I don't want, e.g. old files.

Can someone tell me how to do this properly?

Comment: First thing comes to mind: cherry-pick all commits from B on top of A

Comment: @Renat Is this technically different from rebasing?

Comment: Presumably the first commit of B is really the child of the last commit of A. Manually set the parent of the first commit of B (from none) to the last commit of A. (There is *some* command to do this. ;)) Then run git-filter-repo (third-party tool) in order to recalculate all commits in B. Then you should have a contiguous history.

Comment: Another use case to combine 2 repositories is **git subtree** / **git submodule**, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories

Comment: Suppose A's head is `X` (2021-12-31) and B's root is `Y` (2022-01-01). Do you want it to be like that `X` is the parent of `Y`, instead of merging `X` and `Y`?

Comment: @ElpieKay Yes, exactly.

Comment: @Guildenstern Sounds like a plan. Any idea how you can do this with git-filter-repo?

Comment: Why don't you want old files? Your git history would become rather messy if some files which doesn't exist anymore because they were renamed suddenly don't exist anymore.

Comment: @Kim What I don't want is to accidentally change the content of the commits in repo B by rebasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a working repository.

```
git init foo
cd foo
```

Fetch the two branches into the repository.

```
git fetch <url_to_A> BranchA:BranchA
git fetch <url_to_B> BranchB:BranchB
```

Rebase BranchB onto BranchA, preserving BranchB's log graph.

```
# WARNING, THIS MIGHT NOT WORK
git switch BranchA
git rebase --onto BranchA --root BranchB --empty=keep --rebase-merges
```

The current BranchB contains the histories of BranchA and the old BranchB.

Suppose the head of BranchA is `X` and the root of BranchB is `Y`. The above `git rebase` might not work as expected. It could still merge `X` and `Y`. I don't know what your branches are like. If it does not work, here's another method that I'm sure can work.

After fetching the 2 branches, first create an equivalent `Y` on BranchA.

```
git switch BranchA
git merge $(git commit-tree -p BranchA -m blah Y^{tree})
# reuse the commit message of Y
git commit --amend -C Y
```

Then rebase the commits after `Y` till the head of BranchB onto BranchA, preserving BranchB's original log graph.

```
git rebase --empty=keep --rebase-merges --onto BranchA Y BranchB
```

The 2nd method first creates a commit `Y'` based on `X`. It does not merge `X` and `Y`. It has the same contents with `Y`. `git checkout Y` and `git checkout Y'` result in the same files.

Comment: This is even more elegant way than how I did that. I have cloned one, renamed its master, switched remote to another one, pulled (now the graph has two isolated components!), renamed second master, rebased one original master to another and renamed the result ot master.

Comment: @ElpieKay Thank you very much. The line `git merge $(git commit-tree -p BranchA -m blah A^{tree})`  ist not clear to me. What is `A`? How do we get the commit `Y`?

Comment: @JFabianMeier Sorry, my typo. It should be `Y`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to

1. Create a new commit from the root commit of the second history: set the
   first and only parent to the last commit of the first history
   (git-replace(1))
2. Recalculate the graph of the second history (git-filter-repo(1))

Then you will have one history/graph.

```
# Assuming branches `a` and `b` from the two repositories
first_commit_b=$(git log --reverse --format='%H' b | head -1)
git replace --graft $first_commit_b a
# Third-party tool https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo
git filter-repo --force
# Should show the whole history
git log b
```

#### Demo

```
cd /tmp
tmp=$(mktemp -d)
cd $tmp
git init
git commit --allow-empty -m1
git commit --allow-empty -m2
git commit --allow-empty -m3
git switch --orphan other
git commit --allow-empty -m4
git commit --allow-empty -m5
git commit --allow-empty -m6
git replace --graft ':/4' ':/3'
git filter-repo --force
# Expected: 6
git log --oneline other | wc -l
```